# Can't find Anaconda3-2023.03 with pyenv install --list

Tags: homebrew, pyenv, anaconda3

I can't find the newest version Anaconda3-2023.03 with `pyenv install --list` while I have found it in the version history.

```
Release 2.3.16
Add Miniforge3-22.11.1-4 by @jlec in #2642
Add Anaconda3-2023.03 by @anton-petrov in #2648
```

I have upgraded pyenv to pyenv 2.3.18 with 'brew upgrade pyenv'
Then I tried `pyenv update`. What does 'not clean' mean? What should I do with it?

```
pyenv-update: /Users/Yvette/.pyenv is not clean
```

I have tried to upgrade to the latest development version of pyenv with `git pull`

```
 .pyenv $ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git/': Empty reply from server
```